# SQL adding extra rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset which I need to represent in PowerBI using matrix visual.
Its basically a dataset having one to many relationship.
An Organization can have multiple parts, one part can have multiple dates against it and a date is having 6 different order types.

At the end I need to represent it in matrix format in PowerBI.
Is there any way to add extra rows in the dataset (i.e. 0 for quantity having no dates against them (meaning not present in the dataset but required in the final report

query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.name,
       a.item_segments,
       a.description,
       a.quantity,
       a.due_date,
       a.order_type_text,
       a.week_number,
       a.previous_week
WHERE a.due_date <= GETDATE() + 90
ORDER BY a.order_type_text,
         a.name,
         a.due_date,
         week_number;
```

[Link of the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z5iScgQ__2K3r-xKiCUci36xdJRL7ETX).

Comment: Could you post the file contents in the actual question in form of a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you need the query behind my report?

Comment: I could probably help but I'd like to see the query.  Without seeing the code, I'm guessing you might want to look into something like the coalesce operator.

Comment: select distinct
a.name,
a.item_segments,
a.description,
a.quantity,
a.due_date,
a.order_type_text,
a.week_number,
a.previous_week

where a.due_date <= getdate() +90

order by
a.order_type_text,
a.name,
a.due_date,
week_number

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra rows with hard-coded values with UNION.